# Problema al hacer update js node-postgres

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, iteradores, postgresql-13

Estoy tratando de hacer una actualización en una tabla de Postgress pero mis intentos han fallado

1)Order me trae mis idOrder y idBranchOffice
2)La idea era que con el map iba a realizar update una

```
(node:7704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 72)
```

(node:7704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.
at Client._connect (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:94:19)
at C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:166:12
at new Promise ()
at Client.connect (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:165:12)
at C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\functions.js:245:16
at Array.map ()
at updateOrderInfo (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\functions.js:242:11)
at main (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\main.js:6:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:7704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 73)
(node:7704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.
at Client._connect (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:94:19)
at C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:166:12
at new Promise ()
at Client.connect (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:165:12)
at C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\functions.js:245:16
at Array.map ()
at updateOrderInfo (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\functions.js:242:11)
at main (C:\Users\arp93\Desktop\api-integrations\main.js:6:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Por otro lado, ¿has intentado mover el `client.end()` a una línea después del `.catch` ?

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por la lectura, lo tendré en cuenta de hora en adelante, y si ya lo intente mover, y me sigue mostrando lo mismo. No se si el tema es que son varios update y no se puede hacer eso y no encontré ejemplos similares

Comment: Por favor ayúdanos a contestar mejor la pregunta escribiendo el código en lugar de poner una imagen. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema es cómo *client* hace el manejo de la conexión. La documentación recomienda usar el mecanismo de *pool* para manejar conexiones frecuentes: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

async function updateOrderInfo(order) {
    order.map(item => {
        const text = 'update Order set branchOffice = $1 where id = $2'
        const values = [`${item.idOrder}`, `${item.idBranchOffice}`]
        const client = await pool.connect()
        try {
            const res = await client.query(text, values)
            console.log(res)
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err.stack)
        } finally {
            client.release()
        }
    })
}
```

Espero que te ayude. Saludos